# How to put the % symbol at the end of the text in a text-box permanently?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textbox that displays the percentage.

I want the % symbol at the end of the text, the % symbol should not be editable but the text in the text box should be editable.

How can this be implemented?

Comment: Include the code you have tried with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in pure CSS using the :after pseudo-element.

```css
.inputbox-container:after {
    content: "\0025";
    margin-left: -25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    padding-left: 6px;
}

input {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputbox-container"><input type="text"></div>
```

Comment: You may want to add some padding-right to the text box to avoid input overlapping with the pseudo-element.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap like [`input-group`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/input-group/)

```css
.input-group {
  display: flex;
  height: 30px
}

.input-group input {
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  width: 30px;
}

.input-group input:focus {
  border-color: #80bdff;
  outline: 0;
}

.input-group span {
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #e9ecef;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  padding: 7px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text">
  <span>%</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
<input type="text">
<label style="position:relative; left:-20px;">%</label>
```